# When trying to access home page, Wordpress appends /wordpress to domain name which gives 404 error

Tags: errors, 404-error, homepage

When trying to access the home page, on https://www.andersonclassics.uk Wordpress appends /wordpress to the domain name as https://www.andersonclassics.uk/wordpress which gives a 404 error - there is no /wordpress folder, Wordpress is installed in the website root folder. https://www.andersonclassics.uk/about works correctly from the browser address bar.

I have four other WP sites which work correctly with similar setup

I checked .htaccess which has has only the standard WP settings.

Wordpress Address URL has https://www.andersonclassics.uk and Site Address URL has https://www.andersonclassics.uk. I checked the database table wp_options fields siteurl and home which both have https://www.andersonclassics.uk.

I've tried everything I can listed for 404 errors in the forums, and even tried changing the Theme to twentytwelve which works on my other four sites.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you work locally on this site with a URL containing `/wordpress`? If so, you'll need to do a full search and replace on the database - the `siteurl` and `home` are not the only places WP stores URLs in the database.

Comment: Thanks Elaine, I'm fairly sure I didn't work on it with a URL containg /wordpress.  I've exported and downloaded the database to Windows and done a search on the exported file for 'classics.uk/wordpress'  and found nothing in the database download file.

Comment: Since `.htaccess` is standard, is it possible it's on NGINX which would have rewrite rules elsewhere? Your host may be able to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks Elaine, your replies prompted me to look for save links.  I tried Chrome and it worked perfectly, I was using Firefox, and I've cleared the cache and all is well.  I've installed and reinstalled Wordpress 5 times and have certainly cleared the cache beforev, but this time fixed it.  Many, many thanks, Peter